# Can I use Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my Intel i7 device?

Tags: server, intel

Can I use Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my Intel i7 device? Or Ubuntu Server can only be installed on Xeon processor? Thanks.

Comment: No, it will absolutely work. I believe all Intel platforms are fully supported. Why do you think it isn't?